# Android: App not started by AlarmManager after app exit

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an app to restart from a command sent by my server, searching on the internet i find that the best way to do this is by using `AlarmManager` so it starts the app at some moment.

So the code i've made this far looks like this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, StartActivity::class.java)
val wait = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3)
val intentId = 123

intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESTART_ID, this.restartId)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COMMAND_NAME, this.restartCommandName)

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.applicationContext, intentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
val manager: AlarmManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

// Set alarm manager to start after 3s
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + wait, pendingIntent)

// Kill application
this.finish()
exitProcess(2)
```

Doing this i've noticed that the app doesn't start again consistently.. sometimes it doesn't work and i have no idea why it doesn't, i have tried changing the wait time, as well as the intent id and exit code, but it just continues to be inconsistent.

Also.. checking the alarm system in shell using `adb shell dumpsys alarm` doesn't show the alarm added by the application.

What could be the cause of the app not starting again sometimes?

**Note:** Phone is running on Android 9

Comment: This question of mine can help you (Though it's in Java!)       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303559/how-to-show-daily-offline-notifications-in-android-10

Comment: @null_override I've checked your question.. unfortunately it doesn't help