# Set an alarm in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm trying to set up an alarm once a day so my user knows that he needs to check the app (extracts data from bluetooth devices, etc)

So far, I have used AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...), and a broadcastreceiver that plays some sound in the onReceive method, but this won't work when app enters App Standby.

Anyone knows how to properly set an alarm that prompts no matter if the device is in Doze or the app is in App Standby?

Comment: Check this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63303559/how-to-show-daily-offline-notifications-in-android-10 It may help you :)

Comment: see Work manager component https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

Comment: WorkManager works on some devices, but not on the tablets we use. Not working if device is not charging (and I think it may not work even charging after a long period)